# Is there a way to render fetched data through an onclick function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is currently what I have in this component.
I am struggling with how to render the API data with an onClick if that is possible.

As you can see I tried to return the h1 tag but I am assuming because the fetched data is outside the local scope It won't return efficiently.

Any help will do!

My code is below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';   

class Input extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: []
    }
}
       
    getAnswer = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        var elem = document.getElementById('Input').value
        if (elem.length > 0) {
            console.log(elem.length, 'the length')
            return <h1>{this.state.data.answer}</h1>
        } else {
            alert('you need to write an answer')
        }
    }

    resetForm = () => {
        this.setState({data: ""});
    }


    render()



    {    

        const allData = this.state.data
        if (allData.length > 0) {
            return <h1>{this.state.data.answer}</h1>
        } else {
            <h1>Error please write another question</h1>
        }


        return (
            <div>
                <form>
                    <input  name="input"id="Input" placeholder="Ask a question">
                    </input>
                    <button type="submit" onClick={this.getAnswer}>Ask away</button>
                    <button onClick={this.resetForm}>Ask another question</button>
                </form>
                 <h1>{this.state.data.answer}</h1>


            </div>
         );





    }


    componentDidMount(){
      fetch('https://yesno.wtf/api')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(yesdata =>
    this.setState({
        data: yesdata
      })
  )}
}
 
export default Input;
```

Comment: Hey, check this out. I did switch to functional components but you will get the point. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-ganguly-ou3fm?file=/src/App.js

Basically what you want to do is move the `fetch` to a getAnswer method and it should be ok. At least it is a good starting point.

Comment: You should update the state from onClick event handler, then use conditional rendering based on that state https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: @NikolaMilutinovic this showed me what I needed to do thank you!